# I want to get values in look in views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get all list value in view in a loop, this is my controller.There is custom Model that i have made. I have tried it with ViewData['devieList'] as well. but it did not work for me. I am trying this since 2 days.your help would be appreciate. thank you in advance

```
public ActionResult DeviceList()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        STGY_SMAPEntities Db = new STGY_SMAPEntities();
        var model = new Clients();
        DeviceList deviceList = new DeviceList();


        model.Items = Db.CLIENT_MASTER.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.CLIENT_ID),
            Text = x.CLIENT_NAME
        }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in model.Items)
        {
            var devices = new Devices();
            devices.client_Name =  model.client_Name = item.Text;
            devices.client_ID =  model.client_ID = item.Value;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEVICE_MASTER DM WHERE CLIENT_ID = " + model.client_ID, conn);
            SqlDataReader ds = null;
            ds = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (ds.HasRows)
                {
                    while (ds.Read())
                        {
                            devices.device_Count = ds.GetInt32(0);
                        }
                }
            deviceList.devicesList.Add(devices);
            ds.Close();
        }
        //IEnumerable<DeviceList> dev = DeviceList;
        ViewBag.deviceList = deviceList;
        return View(deviceList);// (deviceList);
    }
```

Meanwhile I am getting it like this

```
@{int i = 0;}
                @foreach (var x in (List<string>)ViewData["deviceList"])
                {
                    i++;
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @*@x.CLIENT_ID*@
                            <span>@i</span>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @x.client_Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @x.device_Count
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @*<a href="@Url.Action(controllerName: "Home", actionName: "ViewDevices", routeValues: new { Id = @x.CLIENT_ID })"><img src="~/Content/images/copy.png" style="width: 20px" /></a>*@
                            @*<a href="@Url.Action(controllerName: "Home", actionName: "EditClients", routeValues: new { Id = @x.Clients_Id })" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Edit</a>
                                <a href="@Url.Action(controllerName: "Home", actionName: "DeleteClients", routeValues: new { Id = @x.Clients_Id })" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Delete</a>*@

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

I am enable to read my data ? please help

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing the model to the view in the action method, you should be able to do this by binding the view strongly with the model in such as way

```
@model IEnumerable<DeviceList>
@foreach (var x in Model)
                {
                   <tr>
                        <td>
                            @*@x.CLIENT_ID*@
                            <span>@i</span>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @x.client_Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @x.device_Count
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @*<a href="@Url.Action(controllerName: "Home", actionName: "ViewDevices", routeValues: new { Id = @x.CLIENT_ID })"><img src="~/Content/images/copy.png" style="width: 20px" /></a>*@
                            @*<a href="@Url.Action(controllerName: "Home", actionName: "EditClients", routeValues: new { Id = @x.Clients_Id })" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Edit</a>
                                <a href="@Url.Action(controllerName: "Home", actionName: "DeleteClients", routeValues: new { Id = @x.Clients_Id })" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Delete</a>*@

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```